# Jquery dropdown switching issue

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/dyHD7/

Basically I am trying to make it so that when user hovers over text, it switches to dropdown, and when user selects a option or hovers outside the dropdown, it switches back to the text. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method change(), update status_txt with the changed value.

### HTML

```
 <div class="sudiptaDD">
        <div class="status_txt" style="display: block;">
                <span>Unpaid</span>
        </div>
        <div style="display:none;" class="status_dd">
            <select name="status[]">
                <option selected="" value="0">Unpaid</option> 
                <option value="Paid">Paid</option>
                <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
                <option value="Void">Void</option>
            </select>
    </div>
</div>​
```

### JQuery

```
$(".sudiptaDD").live("mouseenter",function(){
    $(".status_txt",this).slideUp(200);
$(".status_dd",this).slideDown(200);
$('select').change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();             
        $('.status_txt span').html(value);
    }); 

}).live("mouseleave",function(){
    $(".status_dd",this).slideUp(200);
    $(".status_txt",this).slideDown(200);
 });​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dyHD7/158/)

Comment: I tried your fiddle, but it seems it has the same basic problem, you can't hover over the options in the dropdown without closing the dropdown

Comment: In this case you obligate the user to select a option

Comment: yeh, but that's not what I want. The user should be able to NOT select a option if he doesn't want to. Now I can add in another button for cancelling the dropdown, but that would just complicate the ui more, as this setup will be shown all over the page.

Comment: Hey, I've updated my Fiddle. It's a irritating problem, I tried serveral things, but I think the only way is to extend the height of the div, if the user is hovering over the options (select > options).

Answer (score 0):

Check this It is not much smooth but I think working as u want

http://jsfiddle.net/dk76h/

Click on text and when dropdown will come use keyboard arrow keys to select value and press enter and then remove mouse from it.

I know it is quite tedious but If u can improve it give the link

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it feels really glitchy and moreover it isn't working. I can't hover over the options in the dropdown without closing the dropdown,

Comment: Edit - I can't ask my user's to hover over by mouse, then switch to keyboard. It is direct opposite of being user friendly...sorry